# How to increase heap size for development server

Tags: gradle, deployment, intershop

How can I increase the heap size for a **local** development server? The defaults is now `-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m` (`../local/engine/nodemanager/config/nodemanager.properties`).

Is there a property I can set in `environment.properties` maybe?

Comment: Which server are you running on?

Comment: This should be configured within the settings file while deploy the server. This is documented in the "Gradle Deployment Tools" cookbook.

Comment: you cant change the settings.gradle on your development server. It will just get overwritten when you run gradlew deployserver. How to do this on actual test/acc/prod server i know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For DEV/TEST/PRELIVE Servers:**

You may have a production, development etc. properties file that overrules the environment properties file using the prio modification in your assembly; Check the "include" closures in your assembly and double check if there is a clause for environment specific inclusions. (e.g. if environment is development, use development.properties)

We actually worked around this problem and made our DEV a TEST server (So build a snapshot type and then deploy with a settings.gradle) to prevent yourself from creating two separate DevOps flows.

**For local DEV environments:**
If its developer repetition you want to mitigate, either don't run deployServer if you don't have to (use dC) OR exclude the responsible gradle task/project from running and therefore overwriting the file.

Comment: no this is just a plain out of the box 7.10 installation with inspired store on my laptop. Nothing special. I don't wish to create a DEV server. I want my local development environment to not default to 1-2 gb heap. The only workaround i see is to manually change the nodemanager.properties file after running ./gradlew deployserver.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect that you are talking about a dev environment, not a server.

Comment: Seems like its the tcm cartridge, not sure if it can diff by version, though.
(used a grep on the gradle cache)

Answer (score 1):

There is a property key that you can use to adjust the appserver memory setting. Even better, you can use that key in your local `environment.properties` file.

```
appserverJvmArgs= -Xms3072m -Xmx4096m
```

This results in a `nodemanager.properties` where both your setting and the default VM args are glued together like this.

```
process.appserver0.command=tomcat.(bat|sh) appserver0 -Xms3072m -Xmx4096m -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m
```

I believe your custom setting has still precedence over the default (still printed out) setting.

Comment: I tried this, but sadly the last setting for xms/xmx wins so i am still stuck on 1 - 2 GB